# Adding CSS card leaves a white unwanted space on website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Unwanted white blank space when using website in mobile mode and the CSS cards were overlapping the container. There are no problems when there is just one card in the container but when I tried adding even just one, the white space is showing up.

Please don't be harsh as I was a self-taught programmer.

[image: This is the website when there is only one card]

[image: And When I add additional cards, the first card can't be seen and the other cards overlaps the container]

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}

/*Media Queries*/
/*Set the media query for mobile*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
    /*CSS rules for mobiles only*/
    #nav-bar{
        background-color: salmon;
    }
}


/*Start of Stack */

#stack-cards{
    display: flex;
}

#stack-container{
    display: flex;
}
.stack{
    background-color: #000000;
}

.stack header{
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #FCA311;
}

#card-css{
    max-height: 50vh;
    border-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 40px;
    background: rgb(20,137,251);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(20,137,251,1) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); 
}

#card-html5{
    max-height: 50vh;
    border-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 40px;
    /*background: rgb(20,137,251);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(20,137,251,1) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);*/ 
    background: rgb(240,101,41);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(240,101,41,1) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}

#card-bootstrap{
    max-height: 50vh;
    border-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 40px;
    background: rgb(90,20,251);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(90,20,251,1) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); 
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide html too ? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the cards with a flex direction: column.

Comment: That arranges the cards into vertical orientation/column, Is it possible to display it in horizontal?